# Quiero modificar varios dataframes a la vez

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

tengo 100 dataframes a los cuales quiero eliminarles 5 columnas y a las restante cambiarles los nombres. hay alguna manera de hacer todo eso de una vez para los 100 dataframes? ya que hacer ese procedimiento uno por uno es demasiado engorroso.

por ejemplo, para uno de los archivos csv hago lo siguiente, cuando termino repito para el archivo numero 2:

```
        #Leo los .csv, salteo las primeras 44 lineas
        E01 <- read.csv("E01.Csv", skip = 44,header =FALSE, sep = ",", dec = ".", fill = TRUE)
        #Elimino columnas
        E01 [, c ('V5', 'V6', 'V7', 'V8', 'V9')] <- list (NULL)
        #Cambio nombres de las columnas restantes
        colnames(E01)<- c("COL_A","COL_B","COL_C","COL_D")
        #Exporto en ascii
        write.table(E01, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, file="E01.asc")
```

Comment: Bienvenida Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Si, hay forma de hacerlo, mediante un ciclo o mediante lapply(). Por que no agregas a tu pregunta el código de lo que estás haciendo para un data.frame? así nos es más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: recien lo agregué, gracias por la sugerencia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar, hacemos un poco más simple tu código, las cosas que estás intentando hacer se resuelven directamente desde la lectura del archivo mediante `read.table()` de hecho `read.csv()` es "wrapper" a la función anterior

```
read.table("E01.CSV", 
           skip = 44, 
           sep = ",", 
           dec = ".", 
           fill = TRUE,
           col.names = c("COL_A","COL_B","COL_C","COL_D",
                         NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
           colClasses = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                          "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
                          "NULL", "NULL"))
```

La llamada anterior reproduce lo que hace tú código, ignora las 44 filas iniciales, ignora ciertas columnas y renombra las que nos interesan. Con  `col.names` definimos los nombres de columnas, y con `colClasses` establecemos el tipo de dato de cada columna, cuando indicamos `"NULL"` decidimos ignorar dichas columnas, con `NA` dejamos que funcione la conversión estándar de R pero podríamos establecer un tipo especifico para cada columna.

Ahora hay que transformar esto en un ciclo que itere sobre cada archivo y repita este proceso más el guardado en un nuevo archivo.

Para obtener una lista de los archivos a procesar:

```
list.files(pattern = "E\\d+\\.CSV")
```

Usamos expresiones regulares para obtener todo nombre de archivo que comience con una `E` siga con caracteres numéricos y termine con `.CSV`.  O bien, si los tenemos en otra carpeta diferente al directorio del proyecto o trabajo:

```
list.files(path="Carpeta dónde se encuentran los CSV", pattern = "E\\d+\\.CSV")
```

Finalmente podemos hacer algo así:

```
for (archivo in list.files(pattern = "E\\d+\\.CSV")) {

  read.table("E01.CSV", 
             skip = 44, 
             sep = ",", 
             dec = ".", 
             fill = TRUE,
             col.names = c("COL_A","COL_B","COL_C","COL_D",
                           NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
             colClasses = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                            "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
                            "NULL", "NULL")) -> datos

    
  nuevo_archivo = gsub('CSV', 'ASC', archivo)
  write.table(datos, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, file=nuevo_archivo)
}
```

Comment: Me funcionó muy bien, muchas gracias!!